# Criar objeto contendo apenas alguns atributos de outro

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonisjs

Existe alguma possibilidade de criar um objeto com apenas alguns atributos de outro?

No Adonis, é possível filtrar quais campos exatos pegar de um objeto da request e já cria outro de forma muito bacana.

Ex:

```
const user_data = request.only(['name', 'email'])
```

Que é a mesma coisa que fazer:

```
const user_data = { name: request.all().name, email: request.all().email }
```

Comment: usando prototype acho que é possível

Comment: Você pode usar destruturação normal de JS, desde que saiba a estrutura exata do objeto e onde estão as propriedades em que está interessado. Esse `request` vem de onde ? Quais são as propriedades que tem ?

Answer (score 3):

Podes adicionar ao protótipo algo semelhante (não muito aconselhado) ou criar uma função para isso. Usando uma função para isso poderia ser assim:

```js
function getSubSet(object, types) {
  return types.reduce((obj, type) => {
    return {
      ...obj,
      [type]: object[type]
    }
  }, {});
}

const request = {
  foo: 1234,
  bar: 5678,
  baz: 90
};

const user_data = getSubSet(request, ['foo', 'baz'])
console.log(user_data);
```